# combining configurations for Toolbar in react-quill

Tags: quill, react-quill

On the react-quill documentation, it shows layout for the toolbar being configured in an array:

```
modules = {
    toolbar: [
      [{ 'header': [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline','strike', 'blockquote'],
      [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}, {'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],
      ['link', 'image'],
      ['clean']
    ],
  },
```

Actual Quill documentation shows `modules.toolbar` as being able to accept a `string` (target), `array` (button objects), or `object` (for handlers).
Is there a way to use both the button layout array *and* handlers? Or am I just stuck creating a toolbar component and defining the handler?

Edit:
Upon further inspection of the Quill docs, I've pieced this together for using quill-emoji:

```
toolbar: {
    container: [
      [{ header: '1' },{ header: '2' }, { font: [] }], [{ size: [] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
      [ { list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }, { indent: '-1' }, { indent: '+1' }, ],
      ['link', 'image', 'video'],
      ['emoji'],
      ['clean'],
    ],
    "emoji-toolbar": true,
    "emoji-textarea": true,
    "emoji-shortname": true,
    handlers: {'emoji': function() {}},
  },
```

The editor renders, but there is no emoji button.